# 'Start a Bounty' deserves better look and feel, was not easily picked up by eyes

Tags: discussion, bounty

Today I was  going to start a bounty on one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42506307/681929) but I scrolled the question's screen up and down and after 15 secs, I discovered 'START A BOUNTY'  finally. It was hidden deep down in the middle of the screen, with:

- no highlight
- no different text color
- not any background

  to differentiate it from other components. Believe me I perform and do things quickly when I know where to find them. But I suspect that this 'Start a bounty' deserves better look and feel so that it can be easily identified on the screen.

[image]

The option seems like an orphan :/

Comment: I keep clicking on it instead of "add a comment" because they're so close together and barely differentiated.

Comment: Little orphan bounty?

Comment: Bounty is supposed to be something done only when you have a great need that permamently damages your precious, hard-earned reputation - IMHO it makes sense that it's represented by a modest and out-of-the-way button.

Comment: @Dragomok That would make an excellent answer.

Comment: What about placing it under the question with the other grey options? It would probably be better suited to there since it's relevant to the question and so technically an option. The word _bounty_ would probably suffice and it creates a popup for the user to then start the bounty as normal.

Comment: @jpmc26 Feel free to incorporate that into your post if you want. :)

Comment: -1 No hand-drawn circles. I don't know where to look!!

Comment: I really agree with putting it as another grey option, as it does not belong in the same space as "add a comment" - I see it as more of a question option. I disagree with a large coloured button - it is easy to get in the trap of wanting things in UI based on what you want in the moment, vs the typical case

Comment: @Chris definitely agree with that. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm always thinking it's a randome commenter telling the OP to start a bounty, it definitiley shoulde be differentiated.

Answer (score 25):

I've always disliked where the bounty link is right now.  It seems out of place and hard to find the first time you want to use it.  Instead of making it a button underneath the comments why don't we add it to the links at the bottom left of the question under the tag.  This to me seems like the place it should be in since all of those links act on the question which is what a bounty does.

Also while they are doing that if they want to add dedicated history and timeline links there as well then that would be great.

[image]

Comment: There is a feature request on meta.SE for this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234095/can-we-move-start-a-bounty-to-a-more-intuitive-location

Answer (score 2):

It seems that **placement and meaning** are important.

*Background: It honestly took my some time (reading all answers & comments) to understand the bounty concept in this context (usage pattern, behavior we want to foster).*

To explain the meaning (very important for non-American users, since "bounty" is a US analogy/idiom) , the text could move to something like "Not enough relevant answers? Place a bounty"

To differentiate visually,

- an icon could be added, not sure which one yet, a *long dark bar* could be misinterpreted (^_-)
- it could be right aligned
- "add a comment" could be a real button instead of a link

Answer (score -11):

I'm not sure I like the idea of making the bounty button more prominent.

Just the other day, I saw [a question with a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42467741/1394393) from a comparatively low reputation user. The question should probably be closed. It's not really a poorly asked question; it's just "Too Broad" because it covers too much ground, in my opinion. I think the user is unlikely to get much of a useful answer in spite of the bounty, just because of the nature of the question.

Because of situations like that, I've always viewed the bounty system as best leveraged once you've acquired the skills/knowledge to be really good at determining whether your question a good fit for SO or not and to ensure it's well written. Spending your rep when you don't have those skills and knowledge is just wasting what little reputation you have.

So I think being not easily noticed is actually an advantage. The users who will pay attention to it are ones that have used the site more and have had more chances to notice it. That gives them a better chance of asking a good question before they put a bounty on it.

Comment: I think the solution to the problem you've identified would be to increase the reputation required to start a bounty - not to make the button to start one less visible...

Comment: @R_Kapp Potentially, but if the rep cap is raised, then making it more prominent provides little advantage. Users who have used the site enough to get that much rep will probably find out about bounties along the way. So they'll know to look for it if they need to draw attention to a question.

Comment: You're asked to confirm the bounty so I can't image the OP has accidentally hit _Start a bounty_ and then clicked _Next_ and gone through the options. As it stands, it does look a little lost.

Comment: @Bugs Hm? My answer doesn't discuss "accidentally" starting a bounty.

Comment: @jpmc26 sorry that's a bad assumption on my half of why you mentioned this question. I don't understand why you have brought that question and scenario into this.

Comment: @Bugs I suggest you re-read my answer, then. My point is that low rep users are unlikely to use bounties to their own benefit because they lack the skills to do so. So increasing awareness isn't really a good thing.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. I however do disagree with that. They'll find it and mess with it no matter where it is unless you hide it and have some shortcut key which is disclosed in the help section of bounties. Of course this is just taking it too far. And it's _their_ rep. They can do what they want with it. It's down to the individual to take the time to understand the advantages and disadvantages of placing a bounty.

Answer (score -42):

To be completely honest here, I don't like the whole idea of the bounty system. I have a feeling that non-bounty questions should be answered with the same enthusiasm as the bounty ones. It creates a place where many non-bounty questions don't have much attention anymore.

Making it even more **visible**, encourages and promotes that system, and for the fresh users like me? I can't afford bounties and even if I would spend my 'precious, hard-earned reputation' I would stay on the level where my questions would not get the attention anyway because of my low (noob) reputation, but that's a different subject.

Comment: The problem with questions not getting attention is the flood of (mostly) low quality questions, not the bounty system.

Comment: Questions can often just disappear into the system. Placing a bounty on it brings them back to the forefront. I had to use the system once and it paid off.

Comment: I understand that, but some questions are truly nicely written and you can see the person put an effort to it and made some research, and for a new user that 50 reputation is not easy to get and spend to attract helpful people.

Comment: @Krystian_K I agree. That's the problem with the flood. Best thing to do is look at upvoting said questions to at least give it a fighting chance.

Comment: I might be wrong here but it feels like - make rich richer and poor poorer. I bet the down votes on my answer comes from people with 10k + rep ;)

Comment: Hard to say "only the bounty questions get attention" when a top tag like C# has a grand total of *31* bounties at the moment. We are clearly answering as many of the 1000+ questions that *don't* have a bounty we get **per day** as we can. To the downvotes, you make the claim that the bounty system causes low-rep questions to go ignored, which at least 7 users seem to disagree with :)

Comment: I don't have 10k+ rep and downvoted this answer. Mostly because this is not an answer; it's a rant about the bounty system, just like the other answer (by a 10k rep user, which I also downvoted).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan and the question is not a question it's a group discussion! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion_group

Comment: This is like saying we should all take care of our old and sick, mentor students, fight fires... always go the extra mile, with the same enthusiasm whether or not we get paid for it. In theory, it's a noble idea. In practice....